# How to get TimeSpan from SafeDataReader?

Tags: c#

I wanted to get the timespan value from my storedprocedure on mss,
but I'm having a hard time how can I get it from `SafeDataReader`?

this is my property

```
public TimeSpan Total { get; set; }
```

this is on my fetch method where `dr` is `SafeDataReader`

```
Total = dr.GetDateTime("HOURSWORK");
```

and I'm having an error but I know that this is wrong I just don't how to work with timespan

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'System.TimeSpan'
```

I'm expecting something like `09:30:21` from my SP where column is that `HOURSWORK`.

Comment: A TImespan is the difference between two Datetimes. It doesn'øt make sense to convert between the two.

Comment: Yes @PalleDue but even if I set the type of my property to String I'm still having an error . My sp produce something like this 09:30:21

Comment: Is this from CSLA? You may need `Total = dr.GetDateTime("HOURSWORK").TimeOfDay;`

Comment: @Enigmativity yes from csla. Still having `Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.DateTime'.'`

Comment: There's no `SafeDataReader` in .NET and and '09:30:21` isn't a date. There's no `but even`. If `SafeDataReader` inherits from SqlDataReader, or the equivalent reader class of another database that supports time-of-day, you can use the [GetTimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.gettimespan?view=sqlclient-dotnet-standard-4.1) method. The base `DbDataReader` class doesn't have a `GetTimeSpan` because many databases *don't* have a time-of-day type

Comment: @JohnPhillipAbello `from CSLA` that framework was built in the pre-.NET days, when the idea of vertical components (from GUI to database) was popular. Even after migration to .NET, it has ... quirks. And design decisions that became obsolete as soon as ORMs became popular. Never mind MVC, MVVM and the like. SQL Server had no `time` type back then, so CSLA didn't support it either.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos is there any chance I can display it as a string either? I just need to get `09:30:21` from my SP.

Comment: What is the *actual* type of the database column? *Actual* contents? If it's a `time`, you may be able to read the value as an `object` and cast it to `TimeSpan`,with `(TimeSpan)dr.GetValue("HOURSWORK")`. If it's a `datetime`, you'll have to use `dr.GetDateTime(...).TimeOfDay`. If it's a string, you'll have to read it as a string and parse it, eg `TimeSpan.Parse(dr.GetString(...))`. Despite the name, `SafeDataReader` is just a wrapper over the actual ADO.NET data readers. You'll be able to read the raw value as an `object` at least